# How to check compatibility of mysql with eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

MySql Connector jar file is not working properly with Eclipse Photon.

I tried following connector version: 5.1.38, 5.1.47, 8.0.12, 6.0.6

With version 5 it is giving error -

> Unknown system variable 'language'

and with version 6 and 8 it is giving error

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

Where can I check which connector is compatible with Eclipse Photon or any other Eclipse version.

I am working with Hibernate.

Comment: Hi @Potter, please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reproduce the problem you are facing, please include the configuration and relevant code.

Comment: What kind of: 1) Hibernate version are you using, 2) MySQL server version, 3) MySQL connector version.

Comment: MySQL version-5.1 and hibernate version-5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `Eclipse Oxygen` and `MySQL Connector version 5.1.38`.

Comment: Not working,still giving the same error - Unknown system variable 'language'.
I am trying the same code  that is given at javatpoint for hibernate(Hibernate Example using XML in Eclipse using IDE)

Comment: Try with `Eclipse Oxygen`

Comment: I tried with Eclipse oxygen but still giving me same 'language' error

Comment: I am using dialect -org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ,can this be the reason for error?